# Negative Surface Reflectance

Tags: python, landsat-8, reflectance

I am using Landsat Surface Reflectance Level-2 images. I have to convert the DNs to reflectance values. When I apply the formula provided in the Landsat8 User Handbook :

> reflectance = Reflectance_MULT_Band*DN  + Reflectance_ADD_Band

in the metadata file, `Reflectance_MULT_Band = 2.0000E-05` and `Reflectance_Add_Band= 0.1`
The problem is I am getting negative values even after  correction for 
the solar elevation angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already *have* surface reflectance, not DN.

You are trying to apply the level 1 TOA reflectance correction to already corrected level 2 data.

Just apply the scale factor of 0.0001 to convert the scaled integer values (0-10000) to floating point (0 - 1.0). i.e divide by 10000.0 or multiply by 0.0001.  See "7.1 Surface Reflectance Specifications" in the [Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Product Guide](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/lasrc_product_guide.pdf).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm new this field and I have began to work on the projet for about a month.